# HighStock datagrouping approximation functions

Tags: highcharts

The datagrouping in HighStock allows us to make an approximation of a unique value from a set of points.

The documentation says that some pre-built approximation function are available :

"`average`", "`open`", "`high`", "`low`", "`close`" and "`sum`"

we can easily imagine that 'average' returns the average of all the input values,
high take the highest, low, the lowest,  sum makes the sum ( not sure what this one is for ?)

the question is, what the '`open`' and '`close`' approximation functions do ?

Comment: It's for OHLC charts. Sum is used for column charts ( if column is volume/production, so it's sum for whole month, right?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, by looking at the [source code](http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.src.js), the "open" (resp. "close") approximation takes the first (resp. last) value from the array (if the group of values is non-empty):

```
open: function (arr) {
    return arr.length ? arr[0] : (arr.hasNulls ? null : UNDEFINED);
},
...
close: function (arr) {
    return arr.length ? arr[arr.length - 1] : (arr.hasNulls ? null : UNDEFINED);
},
...
```